# `onsubmit` of html form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

The html code is simple:

```
<form onsubmit="submitAdvice(this);return false;">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>​
```

And the javascript code:

```
function submitAdvice(f) {
    alert('submitting');
}
```

But when I click the `submit` button, it doesn't alert `submitting`, instead, it submits the form.

I don't know where is wrong.

PS: the live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yc6cq/

---

I just found the reason, it caused by jsfiddle!

[image]

Please note it will load `mootools 1.4.5` on `onLoad` event. Everything will be OK if I set it as `no wrap`

Comment: have you considered registering the event handler properly using `addEventListener()`? Would be much cleaner!

Comment: I just found the problem is caused by jsfiddle. It uses `mootools` by default(on the left panel). Everything is well when I removed it.

Comment: You just create file in your local system and try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML form action and onsubmit issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form onsubmit="return submitAdvice(this);">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>​

function submitAdvice(f) {
    alert('submitting');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this form statement

```
<form onsubmit=" return submitAdvice(this);">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T3Qae/