# onsubmit handler not getting picked up from a required js file

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, form-submit

I dont understand why my onsubmit handler isn't being fired on submit. It is defined in a js file and required by the html file. like so:

```
GMaps.js

window.onload = function(){
(function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
});

})();

function gsubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log("hi");
}

};
```

and GMaps.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps Example</title>
    <script src="/javascripts/GMaps.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=+MYKEY+&signed_in=true"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/GMaps.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map"></div>

  </br>

  <form onsubmit="gsubmit()">
    Search: <input id="gplace" type="text" placeholder ="input a place to locate">
    <input type="submit"></input>
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is just a basic example of using a gmap and I can't get the form to recognize my submit handler

Comment: try javascript:gsubmit()

Comment: duplicate of [HTML form action and onsubmit issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope problem.

Since `gsubmit` is inside your `window.onload` anonymous function, by the time you submit your form, no function named gsubmit is found.

Try this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    (function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
        });
    })();
}

function gsubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Comment: l get this javascript error with your proposed fix: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined`.  There is no event passed in to the function.

Comment: Thanks! It worked once I got rid of the closure in the ejs file in the form