# Form Validation Using JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Form created using HTML
    </title>
</head>
<script>
        function validateform()
        {
            var x=document.forms["myForm"]["txtName"];
            var y=document.forms["myForm"]["txtAge"];
            if(x.value=="")
            {
                window.alert("Please enter valid values");
                return false;
            }
            else if(isNaN(y.value))
            {
                window.alert("Please enter valid values");
                return false;
            }
        }
        </script>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" action="/valid.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        Employee Name : <input type="text" name="txtName"><br>
        Salary: <input type="text" name="txtAge"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="btnOK" value="Submit">OK</button>
        <button type="reset" name="btnClear" >Clear</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

I'm trying to validate my form but it just won't get executed. I don't want to do it with "Id" method. Sorry if I offended some of you with my last line, I'm fairly new in Javascript.

Comment: What is *“Id” method* and why don’t you want to use it?

Comment: hint: javascript is case sensitive. Check the names by which you defined and called the function.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Has a point. It won't execute due to the capitalisation

Answer (score 0):

You might need to return true from the function in case of successful execution in the end. This might help: 
[HTML form action and onsubmit issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues)