# How to change form action according to selected option?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, methods, action

When I'm changing form action using javascript in login.ejs file but its not overriding the form action, can anyone please explain why its not working ?In backend i used nodejs express and based on selected option I want to change the form action but its not working ,it is taking default what I have given in action.

```
<script>
function changeAction() {
    const location = document.getElementById("category_id").value;
    if (loction == "manager") {
        document.myform.formaction = "/manager/login";
        return true;

    }
    if (location == "admin") {
        document.myform.formaction  = "/admin/login";
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
</script>
<div class="container" style="border: solid black; padding-top: 25px; margin-top: 25px">
    <div class="container-fliud d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1><strong>Login</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <form id="form_id" action="/login" name="myform" method="POST" class="was-validated" onsubmit="return changeAction()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Category</strong></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="category_id" name="sellist" required>
                <option disabled selected value>select an option</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                <option value="user">User</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fname" name="email" placeholder="enter your email name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password"><strong>Password</strong></label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="enter your password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Don't have account ? <a href="/admin/register">Sign Up</a></h5>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: if (loction == "manager") {  => spelling mistake may be

Comment: no research about errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are using onsubmit and action both.Event handlers run before default actions. They can cancel default actions.

   Since the onsubmit handler always returns false if not admin or 
   manager,the action='/login' never works.

   [onsubmit and form action together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues)
2. Spelling of location  is wrong.

```html
<script>
function changeAction() {
    const location = document.getElementById("category_id").value;
    if (location == "manager") {
        document.myform.formaction = "/manager/login";
        console.log(document.myform.formaction )
        return true;

    }
    if (location == "admin") {
        document.myform.formaction  = "/admin/login";
        console.log(document.myform.formaction )
        return true;
    }

}
</script>
<div class="container" style="border: solid black; padding-top: 25px; margin-top: 25px">
    <div class="container-fliud d-flex justify-content-center">
        <h1><strong>Login</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <form id="form_id" action="/login" name="myform" method="POST" class="was-validated" onsubmit="return changeAction()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Category</strong></label>
            <select class="form-control" id="category_id" name="sellist" required>
                <option disabled selected value>select an option</option>
                <option value="admin">Admin</option>
                <option value="manager">Manager</option>
                <option value="user">User</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="fname" name="email" placeholder="enter your email name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password"><strong>Password</strong></label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="enter your password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%">Login</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Don't have account ? <a href="/admin/register">Sign Up</a></h5>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Comment: I have one more question regarding to passport.deserializeuser, how can i use more than one table to deserialize in mysql can u please explain me ?