# Calling an API with a button and returning results to callback function

Tags: javascript, forms, api, callback

I am a beginner. I have the following code on a HTML page that calls an API and then executes a callback function which opens a Thank You URL that is dynamically created. It works fine:

```
<script>
function callback_function() {
// Dynamically compose thankYouURL (this is working fine)
  window.location.href = thankYouUrl;
};
</script>

<script src='https://www.example.net/api/?parameter=example&callback=callback_function'>
</script>
```

However, I only want to execute that API code when the user presses a button.

To do that, I have removed the above "

How do I modify the following form so that the API is called and then calls the callback function when completing, just like when executing the API directly without a form.

```
<form method="GET" action="https://www.example.net/api" >
<input type="hidden" name="parameter" value='example'> 
<input type="hidden" name="callback" value="callback_function">  
<button type="submit">Click here</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You could do this by something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262797/html-form-action-and-onsubmit-issues

Comment: That does not seem to work as I am not calling a function in the form. I am calling an API for which I only have a URL, but no function name.